# Read input from bash in Python3

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-3.x

I have this script reader.py:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    self.line=line.strip().split(' ')
    print(line)
```

Also, I create an input like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    cat sample.txt > /dev/pts/1
    sleep 0.1
done
```

read input:

```
cat -v /dev/pts/1 | python3 reader.py
```

where sample.txt

```
1 2 3
1 2 3
end
```

Output is:

```
 [1 2 3]
 [end1 2 3]
 [1 2 3]
 [end1 2 3]
```

I want

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
[end]
[1 2 3]
...
```

Comment: Your sample file has no `\n` (newline) at the end.

Comment: wow, stupid. Works!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample file has no `\n` (newline) at the end.
                    – Klaus D.